# Why is my get_post_meta() not working? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I'm making a wordpress theme where you're supposed to be able to say what categories you want to display on a specific page. To do this I figured adding a meta box would be the best bet. Only now I can't seem to get the info from the meta box. It's probably something very simple but I hope you can give me this answer because I've been struggling for hours. :p

Here is where I try to get it:

```
<h3><?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), "meta-box-dropdown", true); ?></h3>
```

Here is the save function:

```
function save_custom_meta_box($post_id, $post, $update)
{   
    if (!isset($_POST["meta-box-nonce"]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST["meta-box-nonce"], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;

    if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
        return $post_id;

    if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    $slug = "post";
    if($slug != $post->post_type)
        return $post_id;

    $meta_box_dropdown_value = "";

    if(isset($_POST["meta-box-dropdown"]))
    {
        $meta_box_dropdown_value = $_POST["meta-box-dropdown"];
    }   
    update_post_meta($post_id, "meta-box-dropdown", $meta_box_dropdown_value);
}
```

And here is the metabox code itself:

```
//Register custom meta boxes
function register_custom_meta_boxes() {
    //Pages dropdown function
    function dropdown_pages_meta() {
            wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");
    ?>
        <div>
            <label for="meta-box-dropdown">Dropdown</label>
            <select name="meta-box-dropdown">
                <?php 
                    $option_values = get_categories( array(
                        'order'     => 'ASC',
                        'fields'    => 'names'
                    )); 

                    foreach($option_values as $key => $value) 
                    {
                        if($value == get_post_meta($object->ID, "meta-box-dropdown", true))
                        {
                            ?>
                                <option selected><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                            <?php    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ?>
                                <option><?php echo $value; ?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    <?php   
    }
```

Comment: Maybe that it will not help but it's get_the_ID() instead of get_the_id()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Wasn't the problem it seems :(